# JavaScript experts: why does `with` nullify the compiler's scope-related optimizations

Tags: javascript, v8, spidermonkey, lexical-scope

Reading Kyle Simpson's You Don't Know JS: Scopes & Closures, he argues that you should stay away from both the `eval()` function and the `with` keyword because whenever the compiler sees these 2 (i'm paraphrasing), it doesn't perform some optimizations related to lexical-scope and storing the location of identifiers because these keywords could potentially modify the lexical scope therefore making the compiler's optimizations sort of incorrect (i am assuming that the optimizations are something like the compiler storing the location of each identifier so it can provide an identifier's value without searching for it when it is requested during runtime).

Now I understand why that would happen when you used the `eval()` keyword: your eval could be evaluating user input, and that user input could be the declaration of a new variable, which shadows another variable that you are accessing later in let's say the function that is executing, if the compiler had stored the static location, the access would return the value of the wrong identifier (since the access should have returned the value of the identifier that was declared by `eval()`, but it returned the value of the variable that was stored by the compiler to optimize the look-ups). So I am just assuming this is why the compiler doesn't perform its scope-related look-ups whenever it spots an `eval()` in your code.

But why does the compiler do the same thing for the `with` keyword ? The book says that it does so because `with` creates a new lexical scope during runtime and it uses the properties of the object passed as the argument to `with` to declare some new identifiers. I literally have no idea what this means and i have a very hard time trying to visualize all this since it is all the compiler-related stuff in this book is all theory.

I know that i could be on the wrong track, in that case, please kindly correct all my misunderstandings :)

Comment: @Bergi I am not asking why it's harmful, i am asking "why does the compiler not perform its scope-related optimizations if there is a `with` present in the code". Which of these questions is answered in that article ?

Comment: The reason to not use `with` in 2017 is not about optimization, but because we're writing strict mode code or ES6 in which it's not even legal.

Comment: @torazaburo well the author argues that despite all the negative points made about `with`, they all miss one of the most important: `with` hurts performance. I am merely asking why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimization referred to here is based on this fact: the variables declared within a function can always be determined via simple static analysis of the code (i.e., by looking at `var`/`let` and `function` declarations), and the set of declared variables within a function never changes.

`eval` violates this assumption by introducing the ability to mutate a local binding (by introducing new variables to a function's scope at run time). `with` violates this assumption by introducing a new non-lexical binding within a function whose properties are computed at runtime. Static code analysis cannot always determine the properties of a `with` object, so the analyzer cannot determine what variables exist within a `with` block. Importantly, the object supplied to `with` may change between executions of the function, meaning that the set of variables within that lexical section of the function can never be guaranteed to be consistent.

Consider the simple function:

```
function foo() {
    var a, b;
    function c() { ... }
    ...
}
```

All points in `foo` have three locally-scope variables, `a`, `b` and `c`. An optimizer can attach a permanent kind of "note" to the function that says, "This function has three variables: `a`, `b`, and `c`. This will never change."

Now consider:

```
function bar(egg) {
    var a, b;
    function c() { ... }

    with(egg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the `with` block, there is no knowing what variables will or won't exist. If there is an `a`, `b` or `c` in the `with`, we don't know until run time if that refers to a variable of `bar` or one created by the `with(egg)` lexical scope.

To show a semi-practical example of how this is a problem, finally consider:

```
function baz(egg) {
    with(egg) {
        return function() { return whereami; }
    }
}
```

When the inner function executes (e.g., `bar({...})()`), the execution engine will look up the scope chain to find `whereami`. If the optimizer had been allowed to attach a permanent scope-note to `baz`, then the execution engine would immediately know look in the function's `baz` closure for the value of `whereami`, because that would be guaranteed to be the home of `whereami` (any similarly-named variable up the scope chain would be shadowed by the closest one). However, it *doesn't* know if `whereami` exists in `baz` or not, because it could be conditionally created by the contents of `egg` on the particular run of `bar` that created that inner function. Therefore, it has to check, and the optimization is not used.

Comment: adding a few code examples would add to the value of the answer :)

Comment: "*we don't know until run time*" - we don't even always know *during* runtime when the `with` statement is entered. We need to check the object every single time the variable is accessed. Also this of course prevents compiler optimisations that reorder, duplicate or avoid variable accesses.

Comment: @apsillers are you talking about `bah` when you say `bar` ? is that a typo ?

Comment: @Taurus Yes, sorry, that was typo; I meant to name that function `bar` but kept it as `foo` by mistake. I renamed things in that example and edited the text.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, yikes; I didn't even think of that. What a nightmare!

Comment: "because it could be conditionally created by the contents of egg", How could the contents of `egg` create a variable inside of `baz` ? my understanding is that when you are performing an LHS look-up of a variable inside a `with` statement and it doesn't exist as a property of the target of `with`, Javascript will automatically declare a variable inside of global (if not running in strict mode).

Comment: @Taurus (I assume you imagine a `baz` case where you do `whereami = 5` in the inner func:) Even so, before it can decide to make a global variable, the engine needs to decide if `whereami` exists in the current scope chain or not. There exist an optimization to do that quickly (by marking functions with the variables that will exist inside their closures when run), but when you use a `with`, you forfeit that optimization (because the scope parent of the anonymous function -- the closure created by `baz` -- could contain variables of any name(s) dynamically created by `with`).

Comment: @Taurus To put it another way: strictly speaking, the scope parent of the anonymous function's closure here *isn't* `baz`, but rather there now exists a lexical scope object (whose variables are defined by `egg`) in between the anonymous function and `baz`. That lexical scope object can't have normal "what variables exist on the scope chain?" optimizations applied to it.

Comment: @apsillers So, it's basically a "`whereami` exists in the scope of `baz` so i should stick a note saying `baz` is where you should look for `whereami` but then it could also potentially exist in the sort of dynamic scope created from `egg` so i guess i will just not stick that note" (this is supposed to be the compiler speaking) situation ?

Comment: @Taurus Well, I'm using two different models (lexical scope object, which is actually what `with` does, versus mutating existing function scopes, which is what `eval` does), so I might be turning you around a bit. Strictly, `whereami` *doesn't* exist in `baz`, but `whereami` could exist in the lexical scope object that exists prior to `baz` in the scope chain. Unlike functions, which can be statically analyzed and do not change their contained variables (except in annoying `eval` cases), a lexical scope object can change its contain variables at any time.

Comment: @Tarus If the anonymous function had a scope chain without any `with` or `eval` anywhere in it, we could know instantaneously whether and exactly where `whereami` existed in the scope chain or not (because we could collect the unchanging set of variables that exist in the scope chain and never have to ascend the scope chain again for a lookup).

Comment: @apsillers Oh i know `whereami` doesn't exist in `baz` in the example you provided, i was just describing a different hypothetical example where `whereami` existed in `baz`. Also, what do you mean by "lexical scope object" ? `egg` or the scope created  by `with` ?

Comment: @Taurus I see -- yes, we would need to consult the ever-changing lexical scope object first, to see if it had a `whereami` var at the moment, before we could use the `whereami` that exists in `baz`. By "lexical scope object" I really mean an in-memory representation of a "[Lexical Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-lexical-environments)" as defined in the ECMAScript spec, though in this case the set of variables in the Lexical Environment *is* defined by an *actual* JavaScript object (here, `egg`) so there's not too much practical difference in which I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Take this example:

```
{
 let a = 1; //stored at 123
 {
   let b = 2; //stored at 124
   console.log(a/*123*/,b/*124*/);
 }
}
```

And now this:

```
{
 let a = 1;//stored at 123
 with({a:3}){
   console.log(a /*123 ??*/);
 }
}
```